# NaN giving an error depending on Python startup?

Tags: python, delphi, embedding

I am using [Python4Delphi](http://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/) to embed Python in a Delphi program. Versions: Python 2.6.4, Delphi 2009, Windows XP.

The Delphi program crashes with EInvalidOp when importing `json`. I tracked it to the line

```
NaN, PosInf, NegInf = float('nan'), float('inf'), float('-inf')
```

in `json.decoder`.

Sure enough, the command `float('nan')` raises an `EInvalidOp` when run inside Python embedded in the Delphi program. When executed in the command line Python (same installation) it simply returns `nan`.

Any idea what is the difference between the Python standard startup and that of the embedded one that may result in such an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely that Python uses a different [8087 control word](http://www.scribd.com/doc/28346285/COPROCESSOR-8087) (CW) setting than Delphi.

Try this kind of code:

```
var
  OldControlWord: Word;
begin
  OldControlWord := Get8087CW();
  Set8087CW($133F);
  try
    // perform your Python code here
  finally
    Set8087CW(OldControlWord);      
  end;
end;
```

See my [blog article on the 8087 CW in Delphi](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/delphi-michael-justin-had-strange-floating-point-results-when-his-8087-fpu-control-word-got-hosed/) for a more detailed explanation of the $133F value.
It needs the [JCL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/files/) for the `T8087Precision` type (which is in the `Jcl8087` unit).

--jeroen

Comment: Wow. The last I had to deal with 8087 issues it was TP7. It is the right answer, and the code works now without a hitch. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:
$1332 is the delphi default.
$1232 is the value to deal with Python Issue 9980.

```
procedure MaskFPUExceptions(ExceptionsMasked : boolean);
begin
//  if ExceptionsMasked then
//    Set8087CW($1332 or $3F)
//  else
//    Set8087CW($1332);
  if ExceptionsMasked then
    Set8087CW($1232 or $3F)
  else
    Set8087CW($1232);
end;
```